# Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes)

Tags: php, memory-management, programmatically-created, array-push

I'm trying to create a Java file using a PHP script, but for some reason, whenever I run this script I get the following error on the screen:

> **Fatal error**: Allowed memory of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in **C:\filepath\file.php** on line **88**

This is the code block with line 88:

```
$var1 = explode(".", $filenamee);
$var2 = explode(".", $folder);

$filename = "extfiles/".$var2[0]."/".$var1[0].".java";
$file = fopen($filename, "c");
$lines_array = array();
while (!feof($file)) {


    $line = fgets($file);
    array_push($lines_array, $line); // This is line 88

}
```

I tried to change the memory limit in `php.ini` from 128MB to 512MB, but that didn't work. I also tried to set memory limit on the code by using this:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512MB');
```

But that didn't work either.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Why you use 'c' as mode for fopen, it is for writing and you reading the file after it. Also you said you want to create file, but in code it looks like you read the code.

Comment: What I need to do is to create a Java file and then add some code into it. What argument to put instead of "c"?

Comment: With c it will create code, but what you expect from loop?? Your loop reading lines from file you just created.

Comment: So to delete the loop?

Comment: I don't know what you try to do =) May be you need to write some code to java file in loop. And then close file.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is first to create a Java file, then create an array on the PHP script with any code to write to the Java file, and then write the array contents to the Java file. What do you suggest to do?

Comment: Your code already should create file, just remove loop(it cause infinity loop). Or reverse it, to write lines from array and not read lines to array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php):

> **Warning**
>
> If the passed file pointer is not valid you may get an infinite loop,
>   because feof() fails to return TRUE.

Make sure your file pointer is valid, and pass "r" (= reading) for mode.

Comment: But the file isn't exist, it should create the file

Comment: So what are you trying to do? If you call `fgets`, you are trying to read from a file. What do you expect to read from the file if it is created by `fopen`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to Get On my Drupal 7 project and I was changed to sites/default/settings.php file include bottom two line please check below

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); // unlimited memory limit
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);
```

[image]